# Understanding self in python

Tags: python, class, methods, random-seed, seed

I am trying to understand **self** in python, but not getting it correctly. For example consider the below code:

```
class relsel_environment:
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.seed(seed=seed) 

        self.step_count = 0 
        
        self.state = 0
```

I understood that first statement is the class , second is the method, in 4th statement step_count is set to zero and in last state is set to zero.

But I am not getting what self.seed(seed = seed) is doing. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: If this is the complete code, it is not right. It tries to call a method "seed" which isn't there and will fail with an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `self.seed(seed=seed)`, you are telling to the current `relsell_environment` instance that, execute the method `seed` and using the argument `seed` (that use that method) with the value of the variable `seed` received in the `__init__` function.

In other words, when you initialize a instance of the class, the first thing you do in the constructor is call the method `seed()` and pass the argument with the same name received in the constructor.

You need to know that you class don't have the method `seed()`, so it will raise an error.